# Expected data is not equal to set data

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to write a test with Jasmine for my Angular search function but I'm having trouble finishing it.

My test looks like this,

```
it('should return movie data from search query', function () {
  var response;

  $httpBackend.whenJSONP('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=james%20spectre&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    .respond(200, movieData);

  MovieSearch.search('james spectre')
    .then(function(data){
      response = data;

      expect(response).toEqual(movieData);
    });


  $httpBackend.flush();

})
```

And the search service looks like this,

```
angular.module('movieSearch', [])
  .factory('MovieSearch',function($http, $q){

    var service = {};
    var baseUrl = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/';

    function movieseatSearch (url){
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http.jsonp(url)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
          deferred.resolve(data.results);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          deferred.reject();
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    service.search = function(searchquery){
      return movieseatSearch(baseUrl + 'search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4' + '&query=' + encodeURIComponent(searchquery) + '&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
    }

    return service;

  });
```

But when I run the test I get an error,

```
Expected 

[ Object({ poster_path: '/mSvpKOWbyFtLro9BjfEGqUw5dXE.jpg', adult: false, overview: 'A cryptic message from Bond’s past sends him on a trail to uncover a sinister organization. While M battles political forces to keep the secret service alive, Bond peels back the layers of deceit to reveal the terrible truth behind SPECTRE.', release_date: '2015-10-26', genre_ids: [ 28, 12, 80 ], id: 206647, original_title: 'Spectre', original_language: 'en', title: 'Spectre', backdrop_path: '/qSc4L05AnHbMpSk0bsHuX25vX4V.jpg', popularity: 35.166039, vote_count: 850, video: false, vote_average: 6.32 }) ] 

to equal 

Object({ page: 1, results: [ Object({ poster_path: '/mSvpKOWbyFtLro9BjfEGqUw5dXE.jpg', adult: false, overview: 'A cryptic message from Bond’s past sends him on a trail to uncover a sinister organization. While M battles political forces to keep the secret service alive, Bond peels back the layers of deceit to reveal the terrible truth behind SPECTRE.', release_date: '2015-10-26', genre_ids: [ 28, 12, 80 ], id: 206647, original_title: 'Spectre', original_language: 'en', title: 'Spectre', backdrop_path: '/qSc4L05AnHbMpSk0bsHuX25vX4V.jpg', popularity: 35.166039, vote_count: 850, video: false, vote_average: 6.32 }) ], total_results: 1, total_pages: 1 }).
```

I've copied the data from the link `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query=james%20spectre&callback=JSON_CALLBACK` and inserted it into the `movieData` variable.

```
var movieData = {
  "page":1,"results":[{"poster_path":"\/mSvpKOWbyFtLro9BjfEGqUw5dXE.jpg","adult":false,"overview":"A cryptic message from Bond’s past sends him on a trail to uncover a sinister organization. While M battles political forces to keep the secret service alive, Bond peels back the layers of deceit to reveal the terrible truth behind SPECTRE.","release_date":"2015-10-26","genre_ids":[28,12,80],"id":206647,"original_title":"Spectre","original_language":"en","title":"Spectre","backdrop_path":"\/qSc4L05AnHbMpSk0bsHuX25vX4V.jpg","popularity":35.166039,"vote_count":850,"video":false,"vote_average":6.32}],"total_results":1,"total_pages":1
}
```

So why is the expected data different then the data I provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure if it's the anwser, but I did found something. In my search function I use `deferred.resolve(data.results);`. Without the `.results` the test succeeded, but my search function didn't output the data propperly. But adding `.results` to the movieData variable in the toEqual fixes that. `expect(response).toEqual(movieData.results);` Also that line should be after the flush action.